# Delaying HTTP request phases using FiddlerCore

Tags: fiddler, winhttp, fiddlercore

I am using FiddlerCore to test out my applications behavior when waiting a long time for server response. I am using c++ winhttp.h library in my app. I am trying to introduce delay before triggering each async callback.
So far I have tried two solutions:

1. Adding `oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = receiveDelayinMillisecPerKb;` as explained in this  [blog post](http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2013/05/automated-website-testing-with.html), and this simulates slow streaming from storage detectable when `WinHttpReadData` is called.
2. Adding `Thread.Sleep(delayMs)` in different fiddler session state handlers (BeforeRequest, RequestHeadersAvailable, BeforeResponse, ResponseHeadersAvailable) but from my app it seems that all of them prolong the time between `WinHttpSendRequest` method and `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SENDREQUEST_COMPLETE` status callback.

Is there any other way to introduce delay in request in different request states using Fiddlercore?